# Use thesholds parameter in tf.keras.metrics.Recall

Tags: tensorflow, keras, precision-recall

I would like to know how recall gets calculated when multiple thresholds are specified. 
Below is the snippet of description from https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Recall

> thresholds: (Optional) A float value or a python list/tuple of float threshold values in [0, 1]. A threshold is compared with prediction values to determine the truth value of predictions (i.e., above the threshold is true, below is false). One metric value is generated for each threshold value. If neither thresholds nor top_k are set, the default is to calculate recall with thresholds=0.5.

I am trying to passing a list of 3 threshold values , and as per the description I expected 3 recall values would be generated (i.e one recall per threshold) , but it isnt working in this way, only 1 recall metric is generated.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding,Flatten,Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Bidirectional
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras import layers
model=Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(len(tokens)+1,embedding_dim,input_length=MAX_TEXT_LEN,weights=[embedding_matrix]))
model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(9,activation='sigmoid'))
opt=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Recall(thresholds=[0.2,0.4,0.8]))
```

Comment: can you add minimum reproducible code?

Comment: I am trying to understand the behaviour of tf.keras.metrics.Recall with thresholds parameter holding multiple values, so there is nothing to be reproduced here.

Comment: well you are right. I just wanted to copy and paste the code and analyze in my IDE. I wanted the code in that sense

Comment: @eugen pasted a sample code, not sure how far it would be helpful . This is a multi label classification problem.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

To be able to see metric values for each threshold during training, it is possible to write a [custom callback](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback) that will log the value for every threshold at the end of each epoch, e.g.

```
class CustCallback(callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        print(
            "The validation recall for epoch {} is {} ".format(
                epoch, logs['val_recall_mult_thr']
            )
        )

history = model.fit(
    X_train, y_train,
    validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
    callbacks=[CustCallback()],
    batch_size=64, epochs=3, verbose=2
)
```

---

I was confused by the "One metric value is generated for each threshold value" language in the documentation too.  It's not what actually happens. The metric  generated is actually the **arithmetic mean** of the metric across all threshold values you specify in the list.  Here is a binary classification example, where for both True Positives and Recall, one metric is generated with the 0.5 decision threshold and one metric is generated for the provided list of threshold values.

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import (
    callbacks,
    initializers,
    layers,
    metrics,
    optimizers,
)

from sklearn import __version__ as sk_version
from tensorflow import __version__ as tf_version
print(f"The sklearn version is {sk_version}.")
# The sklearn version is 1.0.2.
print(f"The tensorflow version is {tf_version}.")
# The tensorflow version is 2.7.0.

X1, Y1 = make_classification(
    n_samples=10**6, n_features=10, n_redundant=0, n_informative=4,
    n_clusters_per_class=1, n_classes=2, weights=[0.8, 0.2], random_state=42,
)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X1, Y1, test_size=10**6 // 3, random_state=42
)

model = keras.Sequential()
ki = initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05, seed=123)
model.add(
    layers.Dense(
        5,
        kernel_initializer=ki,
        bias_initializer="zeros",
        input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],),
        activation="relu",
    )
)
model.add(
    layers.Dense(
        1, activation="sigmoid"
    )
)

opt = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
thresh_list = list(np.arange(0.05, 1, 0.05))

model.compile(
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer=opt,
    metrics=[
        metrics.TruePositives(thresholds=0.5, name="tp_0_5"),
        metrics.TruePositives(thresholds=thresh_list, name='tp_mult_thr'),
        metrics.FalsePositives(name="fp"),
        metrics.TrueNegatives(name="tn"),
        metrics.FalseNegatives(name="fn"),
        metrics.Recall(thresholds=0.5, name='recall_0_5'),
        metrics.Recall(
            thresholds=thresh_list,
            name="recall_mult_thr",
        ),
    ],
)

model.fit(
    X_train, y_train,
    validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
    batch_size=64, epochs=3, verbose=2
)

# Epoch 1/3
# 10417/10417 - 23s - loss: 0.0857 - tp_0_5: 123905.0000 - tp_mult_thr: 121617.1016 - 
# fp: 5823.0000 - tn: 525617.0000 - fn: 11322.0000 - recall_0_5: 0.9163 - 
# recall_mult_thr: 0.8994 - val_loss: 0.0809 - val_tp_0_5: 61862.0000 - 
# val_tp_mult_thr: 60766.5781 - val_fp: 2210.0000 - val_tn: 263435.0000 - 
# val_fn: 5826.0000 - val_recall_0_5: 0.9139 - val_recall_mult_thr: 0.8977 - 
# 23s/epoch - 2ms/step
# Epoch 2/3
# 10417/10417 - 24s - loss: 0.0806 - tp_0_5: 124853.0000 - tp_mult_thr: 122652.4766 - 
# fp: 5573.0000 - tn: 525867.0000 - fn: 10374.0000 - recall_0_5: 0.9233 - 
# recall_mult_thr: 0.9070 - val_loss: 0.0789 - val_tp_0_5: 62789.0000 - 
# val_tp_mult_thr: 61644.4219 - val_fp: 2889.0000 - val_tn: 262756.0000 - 
# val_fn: 4899.0000 - val_recall_0_5: 0.9276 - val_recall_mult_thr: 0.9107 - 
# 24s/epoch - 2ms/step
# Epoch 3/3
# 10417/10417 - 25s - loss: 0.0777 - tp_0_5: 125268.0000 - tp_mult_thr: 123142.8984 - 
# fp: 5556.0000 - tn: 525884.0000 - fn: 9959.0000 - recall_0_5: 0.9264 - 
# recall_mult_thr: 0.9106 - val_loss: 0.0781 - val_tp_0_5: 61261.0000 - 
# val_tp_mult_thr: 60321.4727 - val_fp: 1638.0000 - val_tn: 264007.0000 - 
# val_fn: 6427.0000 - val_recall_0_5: 0.9050 - val_recall_mult_thr: 0.8912 - 
# 25s/epoch - 2ms/step
```

The validation set Recall for the 0.5 threshold (.9050) is as expected:

```
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score

pred_probs = model.predict(X_test)

for t in thresh_list:
    print(
        f"threshold: {t:.2f}, "
        f"recall: {recall_score(y_test, (pred_probs >= t).astype('int8'))}"
    )
# threshold: 0.05, recall: 0.9748847653941615
# threshold: 0.10, recall: 0.9671876846708427
# threshold: 0.15, recall: 0.9597565299609975
# threshold: 0.20, recall: 0.9526947169365323
# threshold: 0.25, recall: 0.9446726155300792
# threshold: 0.30, recall: 0.9371971398179885
# threshold: 0.35, recall: 0.9298546271126344
# threshold: 0.40, recall: 0.9214779576882165
# threshold: 0.45, recall: 0.9133967616121026
# threshold: 0.50, recall: 0.905049639522515  <---
# threshold: 0.55, recall: 0.8952990190284836
# threshold: 0.60, recall: 0.8855483985344522
# threshold: 0.65, recall: 0.8741283536225033
# threshold: 0.70, recall: 0.8619105306701336
# threshold: 0.75, recall: 0.8483039829807352
# threshold: 0.80, recall: 0.8315654177993145
# threshold: 0.85, recall: 0.8107640940787141
# threshold: 0.90, recall: 0.7819258952842454
# threshold: 0.95, recall: 0.7366002836544143
```

But the validation set Recall for multiple thresholds (.8912) is the mean of recalls across all thresholds:

```
np.mean([recall_score(y_test, (pred_probs >= t).astype('int8')) for t in thresh_list])
# 0.8911693902052141
```

The same applies to True Positives:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

for t in thresh_list:
    print(
        f"threshold: {t:.2f}, "
        f"TPs: {confusion_matrix(y_test, (pred_probs >= t).astype('int8'))[1, 1]}"
    )
# threshold: 0.05, TPs: 65988
# threshold: 0.10, TPs: 65467
# threshold: 0.15, TPs: 64964
# threshold: 0.20, TPs: 64486
# threshold: 0.25, TPs: 63943
# threshold: 0.30, TPs: 63437
# threshold: 0.35, TPs: 62940
# threshold: 0.40, TPs: 62373
# threshold: 0.45, TPs: 61826
# threshold: 0.50, TPs: 61261 <---
# threshold: 0.55, TPs: 60601
# threshold: 0.60, TPs: 59941
# threshold: 0.65, TPs: 59168
# threshold: 0.70, TPs: 58341
# threshold: 0.75, TPs: 57420
# threshold: 0.80, TPs: 56287
# threshold: 0.85, TPs: 54879
# threshold: 0.90, TPs: 52927
# threshold: 0.95, TPs: 49859
```

And:

```
tp_list = list()
for t in thresh_list:
    tp_list.append(
        confusion_matrix(y_test, (pred_probs >= t).astype('int8'))[1, 1]
    )

print(f"Avg TPs across all thresholds: {np.mean(tp_list)}")
# Avg TPs across all thresholds: 60321.47368421053
```